# How to auto change select in accordance with same row table using jQuery ajax change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-table

I have form input dynamically row on table area. My first schema on first row is running well using automatic filling field change ajax function:

[image: first schema running well]

but I have problem in the second row and next row too. When I change the select option on second row, the previous field changed (not same row as what I have changed):

[image: select option on second row]

How to automatic filling same row with the select option..?

Here my html code:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().'back/transaksi/Order/insert_temp', array('role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method'=>'POST','id'=>'Validation_form'));?>
                        <fieldset style="min-width: 0;padding:.35em .625em .75em!important;margin:0 2px;border: 2px solid black!important;margin-bottom: 10em;">
                            <legend style="border-bottom: none;width: inherit !important; padding:inherit; font-weight:bold; color:red;">Form Input</legend>
                            <button class="btn btn-success add_field_button" type="button" onClick="addRow('dataTable')">Add </button>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" Field" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"/>
                            <div>&nbsp;</div>
                            <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered dataTable" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" value="selectAll"/></th>
                                        <th class="text-center">No</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Item</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Konversi</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Spesifikasi</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">qty</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Satuan</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Note</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check"></td>
                                        <td id="no">

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="id_komoditi[]" id="id_komoditi" class="form-control chzn_select_L">
                                                <option value="">--- Pilih Item ---</option>
                                                <?php  
                                                    foreach($id_komoditi as $a)
                                                    {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$a['id_komoditi']."'>".$a['nama_komoditi']."</option>";
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <div class="input_fields_wrap1">
                                            <div><input type="hidden" name="id_order[]" id="id_order" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                                            <div><input type="hidden" name="item[]"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="id_konversi_satuan[]" id="id_konversi_satuan" class="form-control chzn_select_R">
                                                <option value="">--- Pilih Konversi ---</option>
                                                <?php  
                                                foreach($id_konversi_satuan as $a)
                                                {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$a['id_konversi_satuan']."'>".$a['satuan_awal']."</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input name="spesifikasi[]" id="spesifikasi" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input name="qty[]" id="qty" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input name="satuan[]" id="satuan" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><textarea name="note[]" id="note" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <button style="border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Entry</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Here is my jQuery/Javascript code // for first change schema

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    dataTable();
    $('#selectall').click(function(event)
    {
        if(this.checked)
        { 
            $('.check').each(function()
            { 
                this.checked = true; 
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('.check').each(function() { 
                this.checked = false; 
            });        
        }
    });

    $('#id_komoditi').on('change',function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?=base_url();?>back/transaksi/Order/Detail_Item',
          method: 'POST',
          data:{
            id_komoditi: $('#id_komoditi').val(),
          },
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(hasil)
          {
            $('#spesifikasi').val(hasil.spesifikasi);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

and here the dynamically add row input Javascript function:

```
function addRow(dataTable){
var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 301)
{
    $(".chzn_select_L").chosen('destroy');
    $(".chzn_select_R").chosen('destroy');
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
    var wrapper  = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var wrapper1  = $(".input_fields_wrap1");
    $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="hidden" name="item[]"/></div>');
    $(wrapper1).append('<div><input type="hidden" name="id_order[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"/></div>');
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++)
    {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}
else
{
    alert("Maximum is 300.");   
}
$(".chzn_select_L").chosen().on('change',function(e){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var id_komoditi = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url();?>back/transaksi/Order/Detail_Item',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{
            id_komoditi: id_komoditi,
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(hasil)
        {
            $('#spesifikasi').val(hasil.spesifikasi);
        }
    });
});
$(".chzn_select_R").chosen();}
```

Comment: Are you using the same id for multiple elements? It looks like it from the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is, you didn't specify any row number here

```
success:function(hasil)
    {
        $('#spesifikasi').val(hasil.spesifikasi);
    }
```

that's why it's only changed the first element, since it didn't know which "spesifikasi" input to be changed.

**SOLUTION**
 you should have something like this

```
   <select name="id_komoditi[]" id="id_komoditi" class="form-control chzn_select_L" data-spesifikasi="0">
```

and this on your first spesifikasi input

with the value of **data-spesifikasi** is the same as the row number to change.

then edit your **addRow function** at the iteration line, so it will give row number value for the necessary input column

```
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++)
{
       var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
       cellToChange = $(newcell).find('.form-control');
       if($(cellToChange[0]).attr("class") == "form-control chzn_select_L")
         $(cellToChange[0]).data("spesifikasi", (rowCount-1))
       else if($(cellToChange[0]).attr("id") == "spesifikasi0")
         $(cellToChange[0]).attr("id", "spesifikasi"+(rowCount-1))
 }
```

and your chosen() function to be like this :

```
$(".chzn_select_L").chosen().on('change',function(e){
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
var id_komoditi = $(this).val();
var spesifikasi_target = $(this).data("spesifikasi");
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url();?>back/transaksi/Order/Detail_Item',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
        id_komoditi: id_komoditi,
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(hasil)
    {
        $('#spesifikasi'+spesifikasi_target).val(hasil.spesifikasi);
    }
});
```

});

> The number/index 0 is responsible for each row number you use, hence
>   you should change each input you're using to have an index in their id
>   and name to be the same as their row number

**Therefore, you will get different target spesifikasi for each select input**

P.S : Just ask more if you're still unclear about them

Comment: still the same results. I have changed according to instructions. The auto change remains the first element. greetings from gresik

Comment: when i add new row, then inspect element on browser. The data-specification remains in index 0 not increase

Comment: @epm.007 I've edited the answer, try it. haha greetings from sby

Answer (score 0):

Your first change:

```
$('#id_komoditi').on('change',function(){
    //...
    success:function(hasil)
    {
        $('#spesifikasi').val(hasil.spesifikasi);
    }
});
```

Your second change:

```
$(".chzn_select_L").chosen().on('change',function(e){
    //...
    success:function(hasil)
    {
        $('#spesifikasi').val(hasil.spesifikasi);
    }
});
```

Both times you are changing #spesifikasi, so either you have the id multiple times which you need to change, or you have a different id then you need to use that one in the second function.